# Exporting interactive bokeh plots from one file to another to use for panel

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh, panel

Is it possible to export a bokeh plot I created in one file to another file that will be used for my styling and layout of a data visualisation dashboard (of multiple plots) using panel?

I hope to still keep the interactivity of the plot if possible.
For reference below might be an example of a sample code snippet/plot I might wish to export to another file (the actual code details of this specific plot are not important)

```
import pandas as pd
from math import pi
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.transform import cumsum
import colorcet

# Provide some data (is not the same as in your example):
data = {"Year": [1990, 1991, 1992],
        "Meningitis": [2159, 1592, 3914],
        "Alzheimer": [1116, 842, 534],
        "Parkinson": [371, 2376, 1675],
        "Malaria": [93, 189, 231]    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("Year")

df_transposed = df.transpose()
df

# Create one data frame per year and save them to a list of data frames.
# I find it easier to keep data frames at first, because operations can
# be applied at a higher level, so with less code:
year_dfs = []
for year in df_transposed.columns:
    year_df = df_transposed[year].to_frame(name="Deaths")
    year_df.index.name = "Disease"
    year_df["Percent"] = 100 * year_df["Deaths"]/year_df["Deaths"].sum()
    year_df["angle"] = year_df["Deaths"]/year_df["Deaths"].sum() * 2 * pi
    # Compute start and end angle for each disease, so that the first disease starts
    # at the top of the pie and the next ones appear in clockwise direction:
    year_df["start_angle"] = pi/2 - (year_df["angle"].cumsum() - year_df["angle"])
    year_df["end_angle"] = pi/2 - year_df["angle"].cumsum()
    # Set the color column. Feel free to use other palettes:
    year_df['color'] = list(map(lambda x: colorcet.b_glasbey_category10[x], range(len(year_df))))
    year_dfs.append(year_df)
year_df

# Convert the dataframes to dictionaries in the ColumnDataSource data format to hand over to Javascript:
year_dicts = []
for df in year_dfs:
    year_dicts.append(dict(ColumnDataSource(df).data))
year_dicts 

# Setup pie chart:
height = 550
width = 650
plot = figure(height=height, width=width, title="Diseases", x_range=(-0.6, 1.0))

plot_source = ColumnDataSource(year_dicts[0])

plot.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.6, source=plot_source,
         start_angle="start_angle", end_angle="end_angle", direction="clock",
        line_color="white", legend_field='Disease', fill_color='color')
print(plot_source.data)

# Setup hover inspection:
hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = [("Disease", "@{Disease}"),
                  ("Deaths", "@Deaths"),
                  ("Percent", "@Percent{f0.0} %")]
plot.add_tools(hover)

plot.axis.axis_label = None
plot.axis.visible = False
plot.grid.grid_line_color = None
plot.outline_line_color = None

plot.title.text_font_size = '16pt'

plot.toolbar.active_drag = None
plot.toolbar_location = None

# Setup slider and callback:
slider = Slider(start=1990, end=1992, value=1990, step=1, title="Select year")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(plot_source=plot_source, sources=year_dicts), code="""
    const year_select = cb_obj.value
    const source_list = sources
    plot_source.data = source_list[year_select - 1990]
""")

slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = column(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

I tried exporting as a html, but am not sure how viable that is since as far as I'm aware html scripts by themselves typically can't execute live python code

Answer (score 0):

You can pickle a holoviews object and load it on another system, if that helps ...